# Does terminal aliases with the $ escape it?

Tags: terminal, zsh

Does the `$` escape the command? For some reason this shortcut doesn't work for me.

```
alias killmenow="kill -9 $(lsof -i tcp:3000 -t)"
```

Comment: the `$()` is evaluated at the time, the alias is set, not when the alias itself is executed. This might not be, what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Just put it between simple quotes so it is not evaluated during the construction of the alias but when the alias is called:

```
alias killmenow='kill -9 $(lsof -i tcp:3000 -t)'
```

Another solution is to escape the dollar:

```
alias killmenow="kill -9 \$(lsof -i tcp:3000 -t)"
```